# What is the difference between "%[^\n]" and "%s" for scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

What is the difference between the following two invocations of `scanf` and when should I use one or the other?

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", word);
scanf(" %s", word);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%[^\n]` is for reading string until hit to `\n` or EOF. Whitespaces can be included in the string.

`%s` is for reading string until hit to whitespace or EOF.

It is better to specify maximum length to read to avoid buffer overrun like this:

```
char word[100];
scanf("%99s", word); /* don't forget to reserve a space for terminating null-character */
```

Comment: Thank you mate! :D